# Ag grid, how to style floating rows?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there a way to style the floating rows, something like floatCellStyle ? I see that there is a floatingCellRenderer but nothing specifically for the styles.

Answer (score 0):

Well, kinda late but here's an answer...
You can set styles by `getRowStyle` into `gridOptions` like this

```
getRowStyle: function(params) {
  if (params.node.floating) {
    return {'font-weight': 'bold'}
  }
}
```

source: [ag-Grid Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-floating/#gsc.tab=0)